# MvvmCross: Binding nint to enum and converting it two-way

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to bind a native `nint` value of `UISegmentedControl.SelectedSegment` to a `enum` property in my view model. It requires a custom value converter because it's not possible to cast `enum` directly to `nint` and vice versa.

The `Convert` method works fine, so the `UISegmentedControl` picks values from the view model. But when I click on the control's segment, the following exception is raised:

`` (MvvmCross.Converters.MvxValueConverter) Failed to ConvertBack from System.nint to MyApp.Core.ViewModels.MyViewModel+Selection with Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
at MvvmCross.Converters.MvxValueConverter`2[TFrom,TTo].ConvertBack (System.Object value, System.Type targetType, System.Object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) ``

It seems that `MvxValueConverter` [casts on its own](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/bd3a438f8acff76657a743da0669d97254b7aaa6/MvvmCross/Converters/MvxValueConverter.cs#L53) before calling the [virtual `ConvertBack`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/bd3a438f8acff76657a743da0669d97254b7aaa6/MvvmCross/Converters/MvxValueConverter.cs#L62) method. I'm not sure what could be the workaround except for making the view model to use `const nint` values instead of a single `enum`.

```cs
public partial class MyView : MvxTableViewController<MyViewModel>
{
    // SegmentedControl is iOS UISegmentedControl in .designer.cs

    public MyView() : base("MyView", null) {}

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyView, MyViewModel>();
        set.Bind(SegmentedControl).To(vm => vm.SelectedSegment).WithConversion(new SelectionValueConverter());
        set.Apply();
    }

    public class SelectionValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<MyViewModel.Selection, nint>
    {
        protected override nint Convert(MyViewModel.Selection value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (int)value; // called
        }

        protected override MyViewModel.Selection ConvertBack(nint value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var intVal = (int)value; // never called, exception in MvxValueConverter[TFrom,TTo].ConvertBack
            return (MyViewModel.Selection)intVal;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public enum Selection
    {
        One = 0,
        Two = 1,
        Three = 2
    }

    Selection _selectedSegment;
    public Selection SelectedSegment
    {
        get => _selectedSegment;
        set => SetProperty(ref _selectedSegment, value);
    }

    public MyViewModel() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/be4dfea1099a053d0ad850c8b82767624784ca1d/MvvmCross/Platforms/Ios/Binding/Target/MvxUISegmentedControlSelectedSegmentTargetBinding.cs#L42) and [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/be4dfea1099a053d0ad850c8b82767624784ca1d/MvvmCross/Platforms/Ios/Binding/Target/MvxUISegmentedControlSelectedSegmentTargetBinding.cs#L59) the `MvxUISegmentedControlSelectedSegmentTargetBinding` already does the convertion from/to `nint`. So your converter should be to `int` directly instead of to `nint`

```
public class SelectionValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<MyViewModel.Selection, int>
{
    protected override int Convert(MyViewModel.Selection value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value;
    }

    protected override MyViewModel.Selection ConvertBack(int value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (MyViewModel.Selection)value;
    }
}
```

HIH